# [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 3 in subscribe.php on line 54

Tags: php, mysql

I have a error in my newsletter and I don't know what doing wrong. Please help me.
Now I doing newsletter, first time I used MySQL in my code.

Here is the error:

> Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 3 in subscribe.php on line 54

Here is my code:

```
    if($mail == NULL){

    }
    else{
        $token = sha1(time());
        $result1 = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO newsletter (Address,Token) VALUES (\"".$mail."\", \"".$token."\") ");
        if ($result1) {
            sendmail($mail);
        }
        else{ /*This else */
            $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT Confirmed FROM newsletter where Address = \"".$mail."\" ");
            $confirm = mysql_result($result2,0);
            if($confirm == "y"){
            }
            else if($confirm == "n"){
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: If your SQL isn't working, then use the error handling routines in your database library to find out what the error is!

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Plus, `if($confirm == "y")` you should be using `mysql_num_rows()` for that.

Comment: First email is saving to database, but can't save next.

I have problem with that:
 
`code $confirm = mysql_result($result2,0); `

Comment: How I can use this? @fred-ii

Comment: Re-read my comment, it's said.

Comment: I know, I must use `mysql_num_rows()` but how?

Comment: `if(mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0){ // exists }` like that.

Comment: Also, what is the `if($confirm == "y")` for? Are you checking if a column contains `y`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
(...)
else{ /*This else */
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT Confirmed FROM newsletter where Address = \"".$mail."\" ");
    if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
        $confirm = $row["Confirmed"];
    }
    else {
        $confirm = "n"; // Returned 0 rows
    }
    $confirm = mysql_result($result2,0);
    if($confirm == "y"){
}
else if($confirm == "n"){
(...)
```